# TCC - isNull producing inconsistent results

Tags: tcc, taleo, taleo-connect-client

I'm working on a report through TCC that gives me a count of applicants by requisition with various filters applied using a complex projections. One of the complex projections counts a list of Applicants where a specific UDF on their candidate profile is Null. I'm using the Recruiting 17.4 Product, Entity: Requisition, and TCC version 17.4. Additionally, the alias for the main query is "mainQuery".

For some reason, this query produces a count of 0 for all requisitions:

```
<quer:projection alias="TotalWithoutSurveys" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:query projectedClass="Application" alias="Q1">
    <quer:projections>
      <quer:projection>
        <quer:count>
          <quer:field path="Candidate,Number"/>
        </quer:count>
      </quer:projection>
    </quer:projections>
    <quer:filterings>
      <quer:filtering>
        <quer:equal>
          <quer:field path="Requisition,ContestNumber"/>
          <quer:field ownerQuery="mainQuery" path="ContestNumber"/>
        </quer:equal>
      </quer:filtering>
      <quer:filtering>
        <quer:isNull>
          <quer:field path="Candidate,Gallup_5fTeacher_5fScore"/>
        </quer:isNull>
      </quer:filtering>
    </quer:filterings>
  </quer:query>
</quer:projection>
```

If I replace this chunk:

```
    <quer:isNull>
      <quer:field path="Candidate,Gallup_5fTeacher_5fScore"/>
    </quer:isNull>
```

with this chunk:

```
    <quer:isNotNull>
      <quer:field path="Candidate,Gallup_5fTeacher_5fScore"/>
    </quer:isNotNull>
```

It produces the correct values for this query (though incorrect for my purpose). Even stranger, if I replace it with this chunk:

```
    <quer:equal>
      <quer:replaceNull>
        <quer:field path="Candidate,Gallup_5fTeacher_5fScore"/>
        <quer:string>None</quer:string>
      </quer:replaceNull>
      <quer:string>None</quer:string>
    </quer:equal>
```

it works correctly. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The tag for TCC is reserved for the compiler ([Tiny C Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I experienced this of 'IsNull' not being effective with the the UDF.

As an alternative you can do this by using 'isNotNull' and 'Not'

```
<quer:filtering xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
   <quer:not>
      <quer:isNotNull>
         <quer:field path="Requisition,JobInformation,AD_5fdea_5fEmp"/>
      </quer:isNotNull>
   </quer:not>
</quer:filtering>
```